# Isometric Game - Fake Viewport Movement Issue

Tags: javascript, css

Okay, I decided to finally just port everything into jsfiddle because I am at the point where I cannot get this to work.

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/d6wwbo4f/3/

Move around a bit, and you should be able to go under and around those tiles and move freely around the World Map.

The problem is, when the **user clicks on a tile strip** (or close to it), the `.GameWorld`'s event listener gets the target name of the **tile** you clicked on and uses its offset. **This is bad**. I am trying to make it so the `.GameWorld` e.target is always the `.GameWorld`'s target... Irregardless of what you click on inside the `.GameWorld` class. If that make sense.

I'm trying to get those tiles to have a background image effect (that cannot happen because my maps are over 3000x3000 in size and I would have some huge images for users to download.. :P

Edit: At line 19 in the Javascript Window on jsfiddle is where I detect the issue, but just not sure on a solution..

Edit2: I forgot to add some things for Firefox and EI. Only working in Chrome atm.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to support IE <= 10, the easiest solution will be just to add:

```
.GameScreen img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

to your CSS.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution. I've been struggling for hours, if not almost a day trying to figure this out.    Feels like I am cheating myself with this, I guess my issue is a CSS one, and not a javascript one?

Comment: This line of code just makes images invisible to mouse events, so you always have correct `target` value. I'm pretty sure it is also possible to fix this problem somehow in JS, but currently I'm not sure how...

Comment: that is fine I mean, I'll just tell users to upgrade to IE 11!  It's a temporary working fix now though, appreciate it. I might do a bounty on it later for a javascript fix. Cause I'm lost too lol.